# Parse GMT DateTIme

Tags: c#, datetime

I have 03-10-14 18:44:58. The time portion is GMT
where 03 = day 10 = month = 14 = year and 18 = hour 44 = minute 58 = seconds

How can I parse this out? This is what I'm using but its not working:

```
var date = "03-10-14 18:44:58";
_Packet.Time = DateTime.ParseExact(datetime, "dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces);
```

Comment: "its not working" is never enough information. What's wrong? (Ideally, provide a short but complete example. Then start using Noda Time :)

Comment: I will look into noda time

Comment: Your format string contains the text `'GMT'` - but your *input* string doesn't.

Comment: OH wow , think I been looking at code to long. That worked Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course it doesn't work, since the parsing pattern does not match the date string... Your input string doesn't contain the string `GMT`.

Try this instead:

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(datetime, "dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal | DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
```

Here, I used the `AssumeUniversal` and `AdjustToUniversal` flags. Used together, thay'll produce a UTC date.

If you want to convert that to local time, well:

```
date = date.ToLocalTime();
```